# How to view class implementation in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to see how a class is implemented in Qt C++, but not sure how to get there. Any short cuts? or how I can see how a class is implemented, for example. QString.

Comment: The source code is available for the `Qt` framework or even `Qt-Creator` the ide.

Comment: If you want to see the source code then check: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/, QString: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h

Comment: And the implemnetation file: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Two different ways:

### Browse the sources locally

- The easiest way it to install it from Qt online installer. For each version of Qt, you check the `Sources` component, which will automatically download it for you in your Qt folder
- Pull the Git repo directly from https://code.qt.io/cgit/. You can refer to that guide to download the full source: https://wiki.qt.io/Get_the_Source

### Browse online

Probably the easiest, and two places again

- From Qt official repo, here again https://code.qt.io/cgit/
- Or (my preference) from Woboq, as they provide great navigation tools (search, navigate to declaration, definition, uses,...) and syntax highlight: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp.html